# Ubuntu: Keyboard language switching by Ctrl+Space

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

Don't ask me why but I want to switch between keyboard languages (I'm using US/UA) by pressing left control + space. I don't see this key combination in the appropriate settings, unfortunately.

Currently I have Alt+Shift but I don't like it.

Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I do that?

(I'm using quite an ordinary normal keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my default US English Ubuntu 14.04 setup it's located under System Settings -> Personal -> Text Entry. Looks like IBus is set as the IME under Language settings, might be different if you have a different IME installed.

Comment: And might I suggest Super+Space? Ctrl+Space is handy to leave alone for multi-selecting files.

Answer (score 0):

[Xfce4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZZ7g.jpg), [KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657806/kde-plasma-alt-shift-to-switch-keyboard-layout) and [Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language) allows to set custom shortcuts for keyboard layout changing. But here is **no `Ctrl + Space` option**

Here is a way how to add it:

1. Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file with text editor and find `grp:win_space_toggle` option inside. And add a new `grp:ctrl_space_toggle` option after it (it is not strictly necessary to keep order of options, but `Win + Space` is most similar one so it will be more convenient to keep it together):

```
      ...
      <option>
      ...
          <name>grp:win_space_toggle</name>
      ...
      <option>
      <option>
        <configItem>
          <name>grp:ctrl_space_toggle</name>
          <description>Control+Space</description>
        </configItem>
      </option>
      ...
```

2. Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` and find `grp:win_space_toggle` again. And add own line:

```
  ...
  grp:win_space_toggle Win+Space
  grp:ctrl_space_toggle Control+Space
  ...
```

3. Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` and add new line after `grp:win_space_toggle`:

```
...
grp:win_space_toggle  =       +group(win_space_toggle)
grp:ctrl_space_toggle =       +group(ctrl_space_toggle)
...
```

4. Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/group` and add config after `win_space_toggle`:

```
...
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "win_space_toggle" {
...
};

partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ctrl_space_toggle" {
    key <SPCE> {
        type[Group1]="PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [ space, ISO_Next_Group ]
    };
};
```

5. Go to GUI Keyboard configuration tool and select desired key combination. In my KDE it looks like this:

[image]

<sub>＊ I named my option `Left Control + Space` so its name at screenshot is little bit different</sub>